# Slide down view never showing again after first time

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am trying to slide down a view on a button click and on the same button click slide upwards

Everything works on the first time once slide down and slide up is done the again it wont work

```
     if (slideView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {

                Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
                transition.setDuration(300);
                transition.addTarget(slideView);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(slideViewParent, transition);
                slideView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                transition.removeTarget(slideView);
            } else {
                slideView.animate()
                        .translationY(-slideView.getHeight())
                        .setDuration(400)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                animation.end();
                                slideView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
            }
```

it will slide down initially from the parent view .. then on button click it will slide up.. the again on button click nothing happens.. I want to slide down it again

Comment: why not use view.animate for both?

Comment: @Prince Ali view animate is not working for slide down.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? what effects do you get, if you get any?

Comment: @Prince Ali it wil slide down initialy from the parent view .. then on button click it will slide up.. the again on button click nothing happens.. I want to slide down it again

Answer (score 0):

I have no enough reputation to comment.
But, if your view is already visible or even already gone then your error is at this two lines:

```
slideView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
slideView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The view is already visible or already gone and you are setting it to visible/gone again ending in an infinite loop of going down/up.

So, change your code to this:

```
if (slideView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {

                Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
                transition.setDuration(300);
                transition.addTarget(slideView);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(slideViewParent, transition);
                slideView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                transition.removeTarget(slideView);
            } else {
                slideView.animate()
                        .translationY(-slideView.getHeight())
                        .setDuration(400)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                animation.end();
                                slideView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Comment: @jin Happy coding and please don't ignore and tell me if you have any errors, if you don't and it works then please mark it as an answer so people in the future having the same problem can use it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are animating the view depending on its visibility, i.e. `(slideView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)`, then it is not a good idea to set its visibility in this piece of code. You might want to animate it on a different boolean ( in my case if music is playing, slide up and visibility visible, else slide down and visibility gone). If there is another thing changing your view's visibility, then the following codes will work as is.
Inside the onClickListener:

```
if (slideView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
// if the view is not visible, slide it up
            slideView.animate()
                    .translationY( -slideView.getHeight() )
                    .setInterpolator( new LinearInterpolator() )
                    .setDuration( 500 )
                    .start();
                            
            } else {
// if the view is visible, slide it back where it was
// 0 indicates the original position the view was in
            slideView.animate()
                    .translationY( 0 )
                    .setInterpolator( new LinearInterpolator() )
                    .setDuration( 500 )
                    .start();
            }
```

Please keep in mind, this all depends on the visibility of the view itself and on how you do that!
You might need to tell us who , in your codes , changes the visibility of the view to give you a better `if` statement.